# PostgreSQL ArrayField is too slow in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, query-optimization

I'm performing the following query in my Django project:

```
for obj in Path.objects.filter(Q(server_name__exact=name),
                               Q(keywords__overlap=all_words)):
```

The field `keywords` is an `ArrayField` and I'm using the `overlap` filter which is equivalent to something like following in python:

```
keywords.intersection(all_words) # if keywords is a set
```

Now the problem is that when `all_words` is a small list, less than 10, it does the job very fast but when `all_words` is a larger array, more than 20-30, it takes so much time.

Is there any way around this? I tested other ways like the following but it's didn't make any different.

```
for obj in Path.objects.filter(server_name=name):
    if all_words.intersection(obj.keywords):
```

Comment: I don't understand how your second solution works at all. Assuming all_words is a set, `keywords__overlap` would create a `NameError` I think.

Comment: @ascripter Sorry it was `obj.keywords`.